# how to apply textclick in tableview

Tags: android

In android, through xml parsing i have xml file values in tableview now which are stored in an array.
Now my question is i want to apply textclick on that values.
For example: if values are

Lotus
Lily
Rose
Jasmine

and i want to click on Rose
then how can i take particular array value from the table and apply intent on it???

the for loop that i have applied in parsing from where im getting array values:

for (int i = 0; i < data.getName().size(); i++) {

```
         TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
         //tr.setId(100+i);
         tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 

         // Create a TextView to house the name of the province
         name[i]= new TextView(this);
         name[i].setId(200+i);
         name[i].setText(data.getName().get(i));
         name[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
         name[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         tr.addView(name[i]);

         value[i] = new TextView(this);
         value[i].setId(i);
         value[i].setText(data.getValue().get(i));
         value[i].setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
         value[i].setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
         tr.addView(value[i]);


        t1.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                 LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                 LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if it's TableView, than it has some rows in it. Depending on implementation, you may wrap your textView into, for instance, linear layout and add click listener to it. For more information please be more specific regarding the issue.

Comment: or my question can be in this way: how to apply text click on dynamically generated textviews(stored in an array)

Comment: The click action can only be worked with one way - through clicllistener. You may assign a general click listener to your textfields and then check which one was clicked dinamically.

Comment: is it possible in this way? if we assign a button for each row and then send id of each textview(which are stored in an array) to its associate button. and if we click on it, it will send its id info to the server + it gets switched to other page?? if is it possible then pls suggest me the way how can i do this